# Why non-integer inputs cause infinite loop?

Tags: c

When I enter a non-integer value it cause an infinite loop. Do I need to replace scanf? If so how can I do that.

```
int num=1;
if(num==1){
  int slct;
  printf("\n\tWelcome");
  printf("\n1. Login\n2. Register\n3. Account\n4. Exit\n");
  SELECTION: ;
  printf("\n\tEnter a number:");
  scanf("%d",&slct);
  if (slct == 1){}
  else if (slct == 2){}
  else if (slct == 3){}
  else if (slct == 4){
    return 0;
  } else {
    goto SELECTION;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it because your `goto SELECTION;` method is being called when *anything* you input isn't 1, 2, 3, or 4?

Comment: When I input 5,6 or any integer it works alright but when I input 'a' or something it causes an infinite loop.

Comment: If I were to take a guess, it's because you're writing a non-integer value to a memory location expecting an integer. Once it reads the location again in `scanf` it may just skip since it can't assign an integer anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the return value of `scanf` and flush the input:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    bool done = false;
    while (!done) {
        printf("\n\tWelcome\n");
        printf("1. Login\n");
        printf("2. Register\n");
        printf("3. Account\n");
        printf("4. Exit\n\n");
        printf("Enter a number:");
        int selection;
        int result = scanf("%d", &selection);
        if (EOF == result) {
            done = true;
        }
        else if (1 != result) {
            printf("You did not enter a valid number\n");
            int c;
            while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}
            done = (c == EOF);
        }
        else if (1 == selection) {
            printf("You chose login\n");
        }
        else if (2 == selection) {
            printf("You chose register\n");
        }
        else if (3 == selection) {
            printf("You chose account\n");
        }
        else if (4 == selection) {
            done = true;
        }
        else {
            printf("Please pick a number between 1 and 4\n");
        }
    }
}
```

The format string in `scanf("%d",&slct);` is `%d` which means you want to read a number.

When you enter something else than a number, `scanf` returns 0 to indicate that zero numbers were read.

If the scanf encounters and end-of-file when attempting to read the input (enter control-D) then it returns the special value EOF.

Also, scanf does not consume the incorrect input, so you need to explicitly flush it.

Comment: Infinite loop when end-of-file occurs.  Perhaps a different flow when `EOF` detected.

Comment: @chux updated code to handle EOF properly (and better structure to avoid goto)